# Footer/Nav Bar won't stay fixed at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

At the start before i decided to make mulitple html pages, my code worked fine however after making multiple html pages, suddenly my footer doesn't want to stay at the bottom of the actual page but at the bottom of the content. In my other pages, the navigation bar is longer and fits the whole screen whereas suddenly on my main users page it's shrunk in size. Any resolution?

my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Users</title>
        <meta name="description" content="APP Web Task 5">
        <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
    </head>
<!--Text body-->
<body>
  <!--header-->

  <header class="container jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>APP Single Page App</h2>
  </header>

  <!--Section 1, table-->
  <div class="container">
    <section id="sectUsers">
      <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
        <table id="tblUsers" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed">
          <!--Table header-->
          <thead class="table table-bordered table-primary table-striped text-center">
            <tr id="tblUserHeader">
              <th scope="col">User ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <!--Table body-->
          <tbody class="table table-bordered">
            <tr id="user1">
              <td scope="row"><b>1</b></td>
              <td>george.bluth@reqres.in</td>
              <td>George</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Bluth</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user2">
              <td scope="row"><b>2</b></td>
              <td>janet.weaver@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Janet</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Weaver</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user3">
              <td scope="row"><b>3</b></td>
              <td>emma.wong@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Emma</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Wong</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr id="user4">
              <td scope="row"><b>4</b></td>
              <td>eve.holt@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Eve</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Holt</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user5">
              <td scope="row"><b>5</b></td>
              <td>charles.morris@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Charles</td>
              <td>Morris</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user6">
              <td scope="row"><b>6</b></td>
              <td>tracey.ramos@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Tracey</td>
              <td>Ramos</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="navbar">
    <a href="./users.html" class="active">Users</a>
    <a href="./addUser.html">Add User</a>
    <a href="./editUser.html">Edit User</a>
  </div>





    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

MY CSS:

```
.my-custom-scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
  display: block;
}

th {
  background: #67c8f5;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}

#sectUser {
   border: 3px solid #67c8f5;
   margin-bottom: 120px;
   color: black;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #67c8f5;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color:    #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #67c8f5;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: You have an unclosed `div class="container"` tag. Add a closing `/div` after your `/section`

Answer (score 1):

Try `fixed-bottom`

```
<div class="navbar fixed-bottom">
  <a href="./users.html" class="active">Users</a>
  <a href="./addUser.html">Add User</a>
  <a href="./editUser.html">Edit User</a>
</div>
```

To be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#placement)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's better to use *nav* tag instead of *div* tag for navbars.
Your nav is not completed. Take a look at this :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
   <div class="navbar-nav">
         <a href="./users.html" class="active nav-link">Users</a>
         <a href="./addUser.html" class="nav-link">Add User</a>
         <a href="./editUser.html" class="nav-link">Edit User</a>
   </div>
</nav>
```

I hope this helps you, especially the **navbar-fixed-bottom** class.

Comment: I agree with you that a nav tag is preferable to a div in this case. `navbar-fixed-bottom` worked fine in [Bootstrap3](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp), but Maja Bobrowicz uses Bootstrap4 (via CDN in the presented code), so unfortunately this class won't deliver the desired output.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I am using BootStrap4 though I didn't know this note.